# CPU usage when searching using solr

Tags: multithreading, performance, solr, cloud, cpu

We have a solr cloud setup of 4 shards (one shard per physical machine) having ~100 million documents. Zookeeper is on one of those 4 machines. We encounter complex queries having wild cards and proximity searches together and it sometimes takes more than 15 secs to get top 100 documents. Query traffic is very very low at the moment (2-3 queries every minute). 4 Servers hosting cloud have following specs:
(2 servers -> 64 GB RAM, 24 CPU cores, 2.4 GHz) + (2 servers -> 48 GB RAM, 24 CPU cores, 2.4GHz).

We are providing 8 GB JVM memory per shard. Our 510GB index on SSDs per machine (totalling to 4*510 GB = 2.4TB) is mapped into OS disk cache on remaining RAM on each server. So I suppose RAM is not an issue for us.

Now Interesting thing to note is: When a query is fired to the cloud, only one CPU core is utilized to 100% and rest are all at 0%. Same behaviour is replicated on all the machines. No other processes are running on these machines.

Shouldn't solr be doing multi-threading of some-kind to utilize the CPU cores? Can I anyhow increase CPU consumption for each queries as traffic is not a problem. If so, how?

Comment: Doing performance trouble-shooting here is very hard. There are loads of things you can have a look at, fine-tune, do wrong and fix. As you mention the CPU it is likely that you have functions in place or perform sorting. But that is just a wild guess and opinion based.

Answer (score 2):

A single request to a Solr shard is largely processed single-threaded (you can set threads for faceting on multiple fields). Rule of thumb is to keep document count for shards to no more than a very few hundreds of millions. You are well below that with 25M/shard, but as you say, your queries are complex. What you see is simple the effect of single-threaded processing.

The solution to your problem is to use more shards, as all shards are queried in parallel. As you have a lot of free CPU cores and very little traffic, you might want to try running 10 shards on each machine. It is not a problem for SolrCloud to use 40 shards in total and the increased merging overhead should be insignificant compared to your heavy queries.

Comment: Okay. I get it. Just another question off the top of my head. Solr is Java based and Java can easily be multithreaded. So can't Solr be configured to use multiple threads per shard?

Comment: It your problem was multiple facets, you could use facet.threads, but the search itself, I am not aware of any options (it would be technically possible to use one thread per segment, but as far as I know, this has not been implemented).